# How to freeze columns in ngtable and create a scroll bar for the rest of the columns in the table?

Tags: css, angularjs, ngtable

I have a data table in my AngularJS application which has many columns where the responsiveness doesn't work anymore. I am currently scrolling the whole way through the data table, which doesn't look good.

I am trying to find a way to freeze some columns on the right side of the data table so that the scroll will be only for the columns on the left. The data tables contain buttons on the right side, so if the buttons are frozen it would be more helpful.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 main">
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="widget widget-table action-table" style="overflow:auto">
                <!-- /widget-header -->
                <div class="widget-content table-container" ng-controller="getTalentController">
                        <table ng-table="talentsList" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="font-size: smaller;text-align:center">
                            <tr ng-repeat="talent in data">
                                <td data-title="'#'"  style="width:5px">{{ $index+1 }}</td>
                                <td data-title="'Employee ID'" sortable="'employeeNo'" filter="{ 'employeeNo': 'text' }" style="width:50px">
                                    {{talent.employeeNo}}
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'fullName'" filter="{ 'fullName': 'text' }">
                                    {{talent.fullName}}
                                </td>
 <td data-title="'From'" sortable="'inDate'" filter="{ 'inDate': 'text' }">
                                    {{talent.inDate}}
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Till'" sortable="'outTill'" filter="{ 'outTill': 'text' }">
                                    {{talent.outTill}}
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Account'" sortable="'account'" filter="{ 'account': 'text' }">
                                    {{talent.account}}
                                </td>
<td data-title="'State'" sortable="'state'" filter="{ 'state': 'text' }" ng-class="{greenStyle : talent.state == 'Available', blueStyle : talent.state == 'Billed', redStyle: talent.state == 'Blocked'}">
                                    <div style="border:solid">{{talent.state}}</div>

                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Remarks'" ng-click="showRemarks[$index]=!showRemarks[$index]" style="width:70px">
                                    <span ng-hide="showRemarks[$index]" class="ellipses" style="width:inherit">{{talent.remark}} </span>
                                    <span ng-show="showRemarks[$index]"> {{talent.remark}} </span>
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Resume'">
                                    <a ng-click="downloadResume(talent.id)" class="btn btn-default" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="resume"><svg class="glyph translucent floppy-disk"><use xlink:href="#translucent-floppy-disk"></use></svg></a>
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Reserve'">
                                    <a ui-sref="reservation.edit({id: talent.id})" class="btn btn-default" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="save"><svg class='glyph stroked hand-cursor'><use xlink:href='#stroked-hand-cursor' /></svg></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                <!-- /widget-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /widget -->
        </div>
        <!-- /span12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /row -->
</div>
```

I would like to freeze the columns on the right side carrying title 'State','Remarks','Resume',and 'Reserve'.

How can I achieve this. I guess the controller code wont be required for this problem. Currently I am creating scroll bar for the table by applying `style="overflow:auto"` for the outer div.

CSS : https://hastebin.com/wibahuyoxa.cs

Comment: Include your CSS please, and also anything you've tried. Give [mcve] a quick read.

Comment: @TylerH Okay, sorry if the question did not have the required info. Currently I am using (style="overflow:auto") to create a scroll bar for the div. I am looking for suggestions to resolve the issue as I don't have any ideas for the solution atm.